# When are the linear regression parameters of Y and X the same as the parameters of Y' and X'?

Tags: regression, assumptions, derivative

I am working on some simple linear modeling of a physical system and assumed that taking the derivative of an equation

$$Y = \beta_1 + \beta_2 X + \varepsilon$$

would give me

$$\frac{dY}{dt} = \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 \frac{dX}{dt} + \omega$$

with $\gamma_1 \approx \beta_1$ and $\gamma_2 \approx \beta_2$ (but no).

Which assumptions would need to be true for these parameters to be the same?

Comment: It depends on exactly what you're doing and how you're doing it, but it's possible that the discussion (and links) here might relate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362992/why-do-descriptive-statistics-contradict-with-regression-coefficents/362994#362994 ... may be relevant -- in particular, consider time to be like the grouping variable in that diagram (but imagine more groups representing values at a set of consecutive times)

Answer (score 1):

By "simple linear modeling of a physical system" I understand the following:

1. There are two physical quantities $x$ and $y$ that both vary differentiably over time in such a way that $y(t) = \beta_1 + \beta_2 x(t)$ for unknown constants $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2.$  We may write them as $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ when we want to be explicit about the dependence on time $t.$
2. You observe $x$ and $y$ at various times $t_1 \lt t_2\lt \cdots\lt t_n.$  These constitute your data, denoted $(X_i,Y_i)$ at time $t_i, i=1,2,\ldots, n.$
3. These observations will not exactly agree with the true underlying values.

   - Either you can control $x(t),$ resulting in $X_i = x(t_i),$ or else you expect the differences between $X_i$ and $x(t_i)$ to be so small that you can neglect them and proceed as if $X_i = x(t_i).$
   - You have elected--at least provisionally--to model the differences $\varepsilon_i = Y_i - y(t_i)$ as a random process.
4. You assume the $\varepsilon_i$ are independent and identically distributed (iid) with a common zero-mean distribution.
5. You use some procedure that applies to this model to estimate the values of the unknown constants from the data.  For the sake of keeping the analysis short and simple, I will assume you are using ordinary least squares (OLS).  This assumes the common distribution of the $\varepsilon_i$ has a finite variance, say $\sigma^2.$

**It is not possible to make sense of $Y^\prime(t) = dY(t)/dt$ in this model,** nor should we even try.  (In applying the definition of the derivative we would find ourselves trying to compute the limit of a difference quotient of the form $(\varepsilon(t+dt) - \varepsilon(t))/dt$ as $dt\to 0,$ but unfortunately that difference diverges because the distribution of the numerator is the same for all $dt$ while the denominator goes to $0.$)

Instead, **I understand your question to concern estimation of $y^\prime(t) = dy(t)/dt.$**  According to your model,

$$y^\prime(t) = \beta_2 x^\prime(t).\tag{*}$$

The issue at hand concerns estimating this with data.  You might attempt to use first differences of the data as an approximation, assuming the $dt_i = t_{i+1}-t_i$ are sufficiently small:

$$\eqalign{
\frac{Y_{i+1} - Y_i}{dt_i} &= \frac{(\beta_1 + \beta_2 x_{i+1} + \varepsilon_{i+1}) - (\beta_1 + \beta_2 x_i+ \varepsilon_i))}{dt_i} \\
&= \beta_2 \frac{x_{i+1}-x_i}{dt_i} + \frac{\varepsilon_{i+1}-\varepsilon_i}{dt_i}.
}$$

This is a similar-looking model.  If we define the "derived data" *via* the first differences as

$$Y^\prime_i = Y_{i+1} - Y_i$$

and

$$x^\prime_i = x_{i+1} - x{i},$$

it can be written (upon multiplying by $dt_i$) as

$$Y^\prime_i = \beta_2 x^\prime_i + \phi_i\tag{**}$$

where

$$\phi_i = \varepsilon_{i+1}-\varepsilon_i.$$

Because $\varepsilon_{i+1}$ is independent of $\varepsilon_i,$

$$\operatorname{Var}(\phi_i) = \operatorname{Var}(\varepsilon_{i+1}-\varepsilon_i) = \operatorname{Var}(\varepsilon_{i+1}) + \operatorname{Var}(\varepsilon_i) = \sigma^2 + \sigma^2 = 2\sigma^2$$

and

$$\operatorname{Cov}(\phi_i, \phi_{i+1}) = \operatorname{Cov}(\varepsilon_{i+1}-\varepsilon_i, \varepsilon_{i+1+1}-\varepsilon_{i+1}) = -\operatorname{Var}(\varepsilon_{i+1}) = -\sigma^2.$$

All other covariances $\operatorname{Cov}(\phi_i, \phi_{i+j+1})$ are zero when $j \gt 1.$

Thus the $\phi_i$ are identically distributed *but not independent.*  Nevertheless, your assumptions tell you their covariance structure up to the multiplicative constant $\sigma^2.$  This is a [Generalized Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares) setting (without an intercept term).   Solutions are relatively straightforward to obtain and they include estimating $\sigma^2.$  They enjoy most of the usual OLS properties.  In particular, *the GLS estimates of $\beta_2$ and $\sigma^2$ are unbiased.*  That implies **you can use this GLS estimate of $\beta_2$ in model $(**)$ to estimate the $\beta_2$ of model $(*).$**

Notice that differentiation completely eliminated $\beta_1$ from the model in $(*)$: *it is impossible to estimate $\beta_1$ from the derived data.*

---

For solving the GLS Normal equations, note that the covariance matrix $\Omega$ of the $(\phi_i)$ is $\sigma^2$ times the [Cartan matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_matrix) for the semisimple Lie Algebra $A_{n-1},$ whence its inverse matrix is

$$(\Omega^{-1})_{ij} = \min((n-i)j, (n-j)i) / n$$

for $1 \le i,j\le n-1.$  Use this formula to compute the inverse quickly to high accuracy.

Comment: This not only overcomplicates the issue, but it is narrower, in the sense that you started from a set of narrow assumptions, which lead you to consistent estimations by default (the OP seems not to be concerned with s.e. but only with point estimates). E.g. this does not allow the OP to see how the violation of the assumptions might change the results.

Comment: The question asks what assumptions might be made that would help compare the model estimates.  As far as "overcomplicate," I take issue with that because by making standard assumptions (that would typically be used by a physical researcher) I have explicitly reduced the problem to a simple, well-understood situation with a straightforward solution, while clearly exposing the nature of the differences between the two models.  Given the assumptions, my solution is at least admissible, while I believe yours is not, because it neglects the covariance structure.

Comment: Not to argue with @luchonacho -- I love their response as well, but I also love the detail of this response. This provides a helpful path forward for me that I didn't know about.  And the negative covariance result is an interesting bit of information I hadn't thought through.  Time to go read about GLS!  This is great.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume the equation in levels corresponds to the true data generation process (DGP). Then, in discrete terms (i.e. $dt = 1$), you have that:

$$ dY = \beta_2 dX + \omega $$

where $\omega = d\epsilon$.

This "true" DGP in differences has no constant/intercept. Therefore, a consistent estimator of such constant has mean zero. This is, $E(\gamma_1) \neq \beta_1$, unless the population parameter $\beta_1$ is actually zero.

Regarding $\gamma_2$, its OLS estimator will be a consistent estimator of $\beta_2$ if $dX$ is exogenous. This is, if $E(\omega|dX)=0$, or by the law of iterated expectations, if $E(\omega  dX)=0$.

When would the latter not be true? For example, if your physical system has feedbacks, or if Y and X are part of an equilibrium system. These mean that $X = f(Y)$. In this case, the equation in differences has an endogenous regressor ($dX$), and is said to suffer from [simultaneity bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endogeneity_(econometrics)#Simultaneity).

Comment: Could you explicitly show how you determine $E(\gamma_1)=0$?  I don't see how that follows from anything.

Comment: @whuber Well, the DGP in differences has no constant. So a consistent estimator of the constant in that DGP ($\gamma_1$) has mean zero. That is not the case if OLS are inconsistent. But my point is that even if consistent, it will never be $\beta_1$ unless that is zero in the DGP.

Comment: Much appreciated, and I realize that in my haste to ask the smarties of the world, I forgot to be careful.  The process is in fact zero-mean, and $\beta_1 = \gamma_1 = 0$.  So the endogeneity/simultaneity response is my answer.  Thanks.